# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'execute) when i using js

Tags: javascript, discord.js

hello I have a discord bot and I want to create reaction roles but when I execute It doesn't work ? please any body help me

this is ap prt of the code put it only doesn't work actually i tried hard

```
module.exports = {
    name: 'reac',
    description: "Sets up a reaction role message!",
    async execute(message, args, Discord, client) {
        const channel = '974390749862961162';
        const students_rule = message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === "Student");
        const blueTeamRole = message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === "student");
```

here the index.js file
and the code of this file :

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');

const client = new Discord.Client({ partials: ["MESSAGE", "CHANNEL", "REACTION" ]});

const prefix = '-';

const fs = require('fs');

client.commands = new Discord.Collection();

const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync('./commands/').filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));

for(const file of commandFiles){
    const command = require(`./commands/${file}`);

    client.commands.set(command.name, command);
}

client.once('ready', () => {
    console.log('Nashmi Bot is online!');
});
client.on('message', message => {
    if(!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot )return;
    const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(/ +/);
    const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

    if (command === 'rules'){
        client.commands.get('rules').execute(message, args);
    }
    if (command ==='reac'){
        client.commands.get('reac').execute(message, args, Discord, client);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In your command file, follow the pattern on the first few lines.

Instead of `async execute(message, args, Discord, client)`,
Try `execute: async (message, args, Discord, client)`

Answer (score 0):

I think you should replace `execute` with `run`. Change your command file as following:

```js
module.exports = {
    name: 'reac',
    description: "Sets up a reaction role message!",
    async run(message, args, Discord, client) => {
        const channel = '974390749862961162';
        const students_rule = message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === "Student");
        const blueTeamRole = message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === "student");
```

This works for me.

Important note: change all other command files to be like this run function as well.

---

I also suggest following this structure for your index.js file:

```js
client.on("message", async message => {
  if (message.author.bot) return;
  else if (message.content.startsWith(prefix)){
    const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).trim().split(/ +/g)
    const commandName = args.shift().toLowerCase();
    const command = await client.commands.get(commandName);
    if (!command) return;
    await command.run(client, message, args, Discord);
  }
}
```

That way, you don't have to create a lot of if and else if statements for each of your command, and it makes creating additional commands so much easier.